# Can I run a Hosted Service in the ASP.NET Core Web Host? (getting System.ObjectDisposedException )

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-2.2

I have an ASP.net Core web API running the [ASP.net Core Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
In the ServiceCollection, I register a HostedService to run a worker that subscribes to a message bus.

Some messages come from web API. Some messages come from the message bus through the worker.
They all get written to a database.

Presently I'm having problems where when I write messages coming from the worker to the database I get System.ObjectDisposedException on my dependency injected data access Scoped service.

It feels like my worker is somehow using the HTTP request scopes for the DI injected services.

So, could this be caused by  using a Hosted Service in the ASP.NET Core Web Host

Comment: Show some code -- we have no idea what you did to get it in that state. And of course you can run an `IHostedService`. It's part of the framework, not the web host.

Comment: Could you please post your work service's codes and your  data access Scoped service codes?

Answer (score 0):

Do not read messages in a ServiceHosted, you should read it seperately (maybe in a singleton scenario)

If you're reading messages from service-bus manually you should not have that problem otherwise you should not use scoped services for that. for example in RabbitMQ the best practice is to open a connection for each app